# Image is not responsive inside carousel using ng2-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

Anybody know why is the image inside first carousel not responsive?
And how to make it responsive like the second one (Normal Bootstrap version) below. First one was created using [ng2-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/carousel)

[image: ng-bootstrap'd version and normal bootstrap version]

Here is the html I have:

```
<h1>ng2-bootstrap carousel</h1>
<carousel>
    <slide>
        <img class="first-slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="First slide" class="center-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                <p>Descr1</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img class="second-slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="Second slide" class="center-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                <p>Descr2.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slide>
</carousel>

<h1>Normal Bootstrap carousel</h1>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have the classes `first-slide` and `second-slide`? I'm not sure if that is that is the reason for your issue but it is not a scalable approach.

Comment: Removed them, still the same problem. reg., scalable - this is just a **sample** I wrote, the real one uses a `*ngFor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, bootstrap hierarchy gets broken with ng2's tags in-between. adding `img-responsive` class to the `<img ..>` resolved the issue.

**Only** For the sake of *completeness*:

```
<h1>ng2-bootstrap carousel</h1>
<carousel>
    <slide>
        <img class="first-slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="First slide" class="center-block img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                <p>Descr1</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img class="second-slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" alt="Second slide" class="center-block img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                <p>Descr2.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 2):

For image response, Please add class `img-responsive` or add below code

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

Image treatment for responsive design:

Image scale down-up

```
img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Image scale down but no up

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Background mantain proportion and scale by one axis

```
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-image: url('img.jpg');
```

Background deforms but adapt to container

```
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
background-image: url('img.jpg');
background-size: cover;
```